# my nodejs api working perfect with query params but same thing not working in web browser

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express

```
exports.findOne = (req, res) => {
    Geodata.find({'osmname':req.query.osmname}).select({'osm_way_id':req.body.osm_way_id,'osmname':req.body.osmname,'geometry':req.body.geometry}).lean()

    .then(geotable => {

        if(!geotable) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: "record not found " + req.query.osmname
            });            
        }
        res.json(geotable);
    }).catch(err => {
        if(err.kind === 'osmname') {
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: "record not found " + req.query.osmname
            });                
        }
        return res.status(500).send({
            message: "something wrong with name " + req.query.osmname
        });
    });
};

// for get api 
module.exports = (app) => {

   ///onlty app.get with query params not working in browser but working in postman.

    app.get('/geodata/osmname', geodata.findOne);


}
```

Comment: How are you getting `req.body.osm_way_id` or other `req.body.*` variables? Browser can only add query params, Not body params.

Comment: i am inserting query.param in url but not receiving the required output as postman returns

Comment: You are not understanding `query param` is appeneded in the url. req.body is sent with the http request. I am pretty sure you are sending BODY in postman. 
In browser you cannot use BODY. that's why it is not working. In postman got to `body` and remove the json/text whatever that is there.

Comment: can you include the client code?

Comment: Thanks @AritraChakraborty for the help i just remove the body and its working with only defied collection params.